# What does it mean for probability P(V1|V2)=1 in Bayesian network probability query?

Tags: probability, bayesian-networks, inference

I'm using the junction tree algorithm to calculate conditional probabilities like P(V1|V2) and got many values of 1. Can I interpret it as "if I observe V2, then I'm 100% sure that there is V2"? Is it possible for this to happen? or was there something with the calculation itself possibly?

Comment: What language / package are you using. Are you able to construct a small example that shows the result that you are asking about?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think the problem is kind of general so may not have to do with a specific example which in my case is complicated to explain.

Comment: By calculation of cond. probability, I am assuming that you mean P(V1|V2= *v2* ), and that this value is sometimes one.  1) *Can I interpret it as "if I observe V2, then I'm 100% sure that there is V2"?*  No, it
means that if the variable V2 takes the value *v2* then the state of V1, however it is defined, will be observed with probability one. 2) *Is it possible for this to happen?*  Of course, you can have deterministic nodes.  [ ps: its nice to have fully developed questions with examples, language etc so that they may be more useful for future readers ; and this is a programming q&a. ]